# c++ overload generic method, by-reference and by-value

Tags: c++, generics, reference, parameter-passing, overloading

I have two generic methods (edit: actually *operators* but the issue is the same for methods) that are identical, except from that one uses its formal parameter by reference and the other method uses its formal parameter by value.

```
struct shout_t {
    template<typename T>
    shout_t& operator<<(T &x) { cout << x; return *this; } // by reference
    
    template<typename T>
    shout_t& operator<<(T x) { cout << x; return *this; } // by value
};
```

The intention of the "by-reference" method is to allow "large" objects to be used without copying. The "by-value" method is aimed at literals.

Since the "by-value" method can handle both cases (objects per se and literals), this gives an error:

```
int main() { // Here "large object" ~ string, "literal" ~ int
    shout_t shout;
    shout << 42; // OK
    shout << "FTL"; // ERROR: Overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous
}
```

The behaviour I was looking for is *try first if "by-reference" method applies, if not, apply "by-value" method.*

How to resolve this? How to obtain the intended behaviour of two methods that are identical except from their "by-value" and "by-reference" signature?

Comment: shouldn't it be a `const T&` ?

Comment: and you are missing to return something from the methods

Comment: i tried to make a minimal toy example, focusing on the issue of how to direct the compiler to choose the "intended" method

Comment: minimal is fine, but not returning something from a method that is declared to return something isnt a "toy" it is a beast called undefined behavior ;). Try to not introduce additional problems while simplifiying

Comment: you are right, i overlooked that i had pruned away this essential return. i put it back in now. thx!

Comment: There is no way to distinguish between values created from literals and other values. The reason it "works" for 42 is that you can't bind a non-const reference to a temporary object, and you will encounter the ambiguity for an `int` variable.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes you are right about the ```int i; shout << i;``` ambiguity too!

Comment: fwiw, I first read your question as if your aim is to avoid pass by ref when the copy is as cheap or cheaper than the ref. After reading the (now accepted) answer I think my interpretation was off

Comment: your first hint was spot-on though! *shouldn't it be a ```const T&```?* thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two scenarios here, either you might want to change the object passed as a parameter, or you don't. In the latter case, pass as `const`-qualified reference:

```
struct shout_t {
    template<typename T>
    shout_t& operator<<(const T &item) { cout << item; return *this; }
};
```

and otherwise, use a forwarding reference in conjuction with `std::forward`:

```
struct shout_t {
    template<typename T>
    shout_t& operator<<(T&& item) { cout << std::forward<T>(item); return *this; }
};
```

Comment: thx! great, that solved my problem, no overload, just use const& (facepalm)